# socket.io Detect what room a user has disconnected from

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have found a few solutions but they seem dates and are not working.

How can I detect what room a user was disconnected from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean about room , but if it is a chat app or something like that
you can create a variable on socket object like roomID when first connection.

```
io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
    socket.on("new:user",function(userDATA){
        // create variable as roomID on socket.
        socket.roomID = userDATA.roomID
    }); 

    // other events 

    socket.on("disconnect",function(data){
        var roomID = socket.roomID;
        // do what you want to do
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With socket.io 1.0 you can do this with following code:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log(socket.rooms);
});
```

It will output an array of rooms the user was joined to.

Note that each socket automatically joins a room named with this socket's ID. So you might see something like

```
[ 'hIP6r4z8Ym1n5SQUAAAA', 'my_room_name' ]
```

in your console.

Answer (score 0):

in version 4 and above, if you connect to socket socket io automaticlly create a unique socketId.
if you have several rooms you must create array of abject and save rooms and it's users(socktIds) in it.

if disconnect a socket you can find easily in that array then you can find the room.